# YamlDotNet - Serialization of Guid properties generates empty brackets

Tags: vb.net, yaml, yamldotnet

I am using YamlDotNet library to serialize some objects in Yaml. I've met some problems with the serialization of Guid properties. 
Serialization of Guid properties generates empty brackets ( ex: {} )

See code below

```
Dim l As New List(Of Person)
l.Add(New Person() With {.Firstname = "MyFirstName", .Lastname = "MyLastName", .Id = Guid.NewGuid()})

Using sw As New StreamWriter("output.yaml", False)
    Dim serializer = New Serializer()
    serializer.Serialize(sw, l)
End Using
```

this code will output :

```
- Id: {}
  Firstname: MyFirstName
  Lastname: MyLastName
```

With the class:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Id As Guid
    Public Property Frstname As String
    Public Property Lastname As String
End Class
```

Am I missing something or is this an issue of the library ?

Comment: The library issue is not throwing an exception for types that are not supported in YAML.

Comment: So Guid type is not supported by YamlDotNet Serialization/Deserialization  ? 
 I was expecting the library to output something like {1234564-1232132-21321321} and then this string can be easily parsed as a system.guid ...

Comment: The Guid type is not natively supported, but adding support is trivial. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom converter to use when you need to customize the serialization of a type. The converter needs to implement [IYamlTypeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/IYamlTypeConverter.cs), and be registered on the `Serializer` or `Deserializer`. Here is an example of such a converter:

```
Public Class GuidConverter
    Implements IYamlTypeConverter

    Public Function Accepts(type As Type) As Boolean Implements IYamlTypeConverter.Accepts
        Return type = GetType(Guid)
    End Function

    Public Function ReadYaml(parser As IParser, type As Type) As Object Implements IYamlTypeConverter.ReadYaml
        Dim reader = New EventReader(parser)
        Dim scalar = reader.Expect(Of Scalar)()
        Return Guid.Parse(scalar.Value)
    End Function

    Public Sub WriteYaml(emitter As IEmitter, value As Object, type As Type) Implements IYamlTypeConverter.WriteYaml
        emitter.Emit(New Scalar(value.ToString()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The usage is quite simple:

```
Dim serializer = New Serializer()
serializer.RegisterTypeConverter(New GuidConverter())
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, New With {.id = Guid.NewGuid()})
```

You can see a [fully working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/72kQGO).

Comment: How would deserializing work for this example? Trying to deserialize the output `id: eff34230-ed6c-4c88-aaba-6f6a177c733c` back into a `Guid` throws an exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/exp9su